# general solution of differential equation of order 4

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

How to find the general solution of the following differential equation
 \begin{equation}
z_{xxxx}+2a^{2}z_{xx}+a^{2}(a^{2}-b^{2})z=0
\end{equation}
 If possible to write the answer in details because I searched on google for it but there was no detailed solution.

Comment: This isn't really a pde

Answer (score 3):

This is a DE with constant coefficients. So, let $z=e^{rx}$ is a solution of it, then we have
$$r^4e^{rx}+2a^2r^2e^{rx}+a^2(a^2-b^2)e^{rx}=0$$
i.e.
$$r^4+2a^2r^2+a^2(a^2-b^2)=0 $$ 
which can be solved easily, 
$$r^2=\frac{-2a^2\pm\sqrt{4a^4-4a^2(a^2-b^2)} }{2}=\frac{-2a^2\pm2ab }{2}=-a^2\pm ab. $$

---

Thus the solution is $$z=c_1e^{\sqrt{ab-a^2}x}+c_2e^{-\sqrt{ab-a^2}x}+c_3e^{\sqrt{-ab-a^2}x}+c_4e^{-\sqrt{-ab-a^2}x}$$

Comment: I want the way that contains that  \begin{equation}  z=c_{1}e^{r_{1}x}+c_{2}e^{r_{2}x}+c_{3}e^{r_{3}x}+c_{4}e^{r_{4}x}\end{equation}  and I want the $r_{i}$. this is exactly what I need to find in the problem I am solving.

Comment: You also need to deal with various degenerate cases when you don't get distinct roots.  That's why I didn't do it in [this answer](/a/3234567/592552) to your other question.

Comment: If I want to find the coefficients $c_{i}$ using the conditions that $$z(l)=z_{x}(l)=z_{xx}(l)=z_{xx}(l)=0$$, can you help me in this

Comment: You need to solve a linear system of four variables $c_i$ using four equation $z(l)=z_x(l)=x_{xx}(x)=z_{xxx}(l)=0$n noting that $z_x=\sum_{i=1}^4c_ir_i e^{r_ix}$ and so on.